# display:table - override height and overflow?

Tags: css, styles

I have a `div` which I am trying to animate from `0px` to `npx`.

The problem is it's set to `display:table` which seems to force it to ignore height and overflow styles. This is probably how it's supposed to work, but is there a way of making the table `0px` in height?

Comment: can you show us your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the div has some content and 'display: table' property - it wont get smaller then content anyway.